# Solving for Normal Force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, newtonian-gravity, friction, free-body-diagram

I'm working through [The Nature of Code](http://natureofcode.com/), which is an awesome book, lots of fun.

I've come across Exercise 3.13 and I'm not sure how to solve it. I'm assuming that the force of gravity and the force of friction are provided. I'm not sure in which directions to draw my right triangles to solve for the normal force. Can someone provide an explanation?

> Using trigonometry, what is the magnitude of the normal force in the
>   illustration on the right (the force perpendicular to the incline on
>   which the sled rests)? Note that, as indicated, the “normal” force is
>   a component of the force of gravity.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Being a homework-like question, I'll only give a hint.

After breaking up your forces into components (i.e., into two sides of a right triangle), your original force vector arrow should be the *hypotenuse* of your resulting triangle.

So, for example, if you wanted to break $\vec F_\text{gravity}$ into horizontal & vertical components... well, that's already done for you.

But if you wanted to break $\vec F_\text{gravity}$ into components parallel and perpendicular to the ramp, just make sure the original arrow is the hypotenuse of your right angle. And one of the two sides of your right triangle is parallel to the ramp. The other is perpendicular.

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is to resolve Fgrav into its components in the direction of the slope and the direction of the normal to the slope (which by definition is at right angles to the slope).

Answer (score 0):

$$\vec{F}_{friction} + \vec{F}_{gravity} + \vec{F}_{normal} = 0$$ 
if you assume that the sled rests.

Then

$$ \vec{F}_{normal} = - \vec{F}_{friction} - \vec{F}_{gravity} = - \vec{F}_f - \vec{F}_g$$

Now compute the magnitude:

$$ (\vec{F}_{normal})^2 = (- \vec{F}_f - \vec{F}_g)^2 = (\vec{F}_f)^2 + (\vec{F}_g)^2 + 2 \cos{\alpha} |\vec{F}_f| |\vec{F}_g|$$
where $\alpha$ is the angle between the two vectors $\vec{F}_f$ and $\vec{F}_g$. In this case it is  $\alpha = \pi - \theta$.

Then 
$$ (\vec{F}_{normal})^2 =  (\vec{F}_f)^2 + (\vec{F}_g)^2 + 2 \sin{\theta} |\vec{F}_f| |\vec{F}_g|$$

and finally

$$ |\vec{F}_{normal}| = \sqrt{(\vec{F}_f)^2 + (\vec{F}_g)^2 + 2 \sin{\theta} |\vec{F}_f| |\vec{F}_g|} $$